# Perl to MySQL html text

Tags: html, mysql, perl, unicode

I am parsing some html thus:

```
use Modern::Perl;
use Mojo::DOM;
use strict;
use DBI;
use DBD::mysql;
use utf8::all;

my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:db_name", "db_username") or die ("Error:  
$DBI::errstr");

my $html = do { local $/; <DATA> };
my $dom = Mojo::DOM->new($html);
my $text = $dom->all_text;
say $text;

my ($var1, $var2, $var3);  #normally have values assigned, but not relevant to example

#write $text to MySQL database 
$dbh->do("INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (?,?,?,?)",
                            undef,
$var1, $var2, $var3, $text
);


__DATA__
<div class="field-content"><p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>Here is some data with a trademark html symbol SUPER PRODUCT&trade;, featuring curved
LCD screen.</p></div>
```

Writing the parsed text to standard output produces the following:

```
Here is some data with a trademark html symbol SUPER PRODUCT™, featuring curved LCD 
screen.
```

All is good and this is written to MySQL.  However, within MySQL and in extracting the data from MySQL we get this:

```
Here is some data with a trademark html symbol SUPER PRODUCTâ„¢, featuring curved LCD
screen.
```

I suspected this was to do with Unicode, so tried changing MySQL status settings, but still no joy.  How to solve this properly?

Comment: How do you get the data *out of* the DB? It seems you forgot to decode *there*. UTF8-encoded strings are binary data all right, and subsequently may look like gibberish when viewed undecoded.

Comment: As per question:  "However, within MySQL and in extracting the data from MySQL" - in other words when viewing the entry within a query *in* the DB - no extract code needed...

Comment: Not neccessarily irrelevant… how do you set up your database handle? The code fragment `do`ing the SQL statement is highly uninformative…

Comment: updated, not sure why.

Answer (score 2):

This statement

```
#write $text to MySQL database
```

glosses over a lot of important details, and you didn't include the code that describes how you read text from the database, which can also be tricky to get right.

Let me make an educated guess that the text in your database is UTF-8 encoded. Then you will want to decode all content that comes out of that database column:

```
use Encode;
$decoded_text = Encode::decode("utf-8", $raw_text);

# since you 'use utf8::all', this will get re-encoded to UTF-8 when you write
# it to standard output ...
print "decoded text is $decoded_text\n";
```

Comment: Code to extract not relevant since visiting MySQL and querying data shows the problem.  For code to write to DB, I will add to original question..

Comment: Code to extract not relevant since text problem shows in MySQL and querying data shows the problem.  Have updated question for code to write to MySQL

Comment: No, it's the most relevant part. `â„¢` (0xE2+0x84+0xA2) is the correct UTF-8 encoding for the trademark sign. If `SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME` in the mysql client command line is your "code to extract", then the MySQL output is correct for the "raw" or "latin1" encoding of your data. If that's not good enough, then you need at least one more line of extraction code. You can either do it in Perl (as in my answer), or in MySQL (maybe something like `SELECT CONVERT(field USING UTF8) FROM table_name`, but I'm less sure about how to do that).

Comment: The preferable behaviour would be for MySQL to store the TM symbol as TM.

Comment: MySQL has stored the symbol correctly with a UTF-8 encoding. The problem is not MySQL (or Perl). The problem is that you are trying to read it with a latin1 encoding.

Comment: Understood.  And thanks for the code example on decoding - works fine.  However, in an ideal world I'd like not to be messing around coding and unencoding in reading and writing scripts, and even to see the data within MySQL, so how do I get MySQL to store it with a latin1 encoding?  Is it even possible to do that for a TM symbol, and if not how would I know?

Comment: latin1 is an 8-bit, single byte encoding, and the trademark symbol is not among the 256 supported characters: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1